# Mongoose - sub document validation not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema that looks like so:

```
var minderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  phones: {type: [{
    details: {
      type: {
        country_code: { type: String, required: true },
        region_code: { type: String, required: true },
        number: { type: Number, required: true }
      },
      required: true
    },
  }], required: true},
})
```

That is... a minder is made up of an array of phones (which are required). Each phone must have a country code, region code and number. Yet the validation does not seem to work. I.e. I can create:

```
var minder = new Minder({
  "phones": [{
     details: {
        number: "3343434"
     }
   }]
});
```

Which should not work, because it's missing a country code and region code. In fact I can create a document like this:

```
var minder = new Minder({
  "phones": [{
    details: {
      "sdf":"sdf"
    }
  }]
});
```

And it validates.

What concept am I missing?

Comment: Document would be checked on insert, not on creation. Did you succeed in inserting such documents into db?

Comment: Yeah, I did. It was odd.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is mostly in how you have constructed your "details" entry here. So despite what you think you may have done, the type of entry that is actually here is a plain sub-document or what would generally be referred to as a "hash/map or dict" depending on which term you are most familiar with.

These are not strictly speaking "typed" in any way, so there is no real control over the "keys" you are placing in there. So what you probably want is something that can actually be structured in a strictly typed way, for example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var phonesSchema = new Schema({
  country_code: { type: String, required: true },
  region_code: { type: String, required: true },
  number: { type: String, required: true }
});

var minderSchema = new Schema({

  phones:[phonesSchema]

});


var Minder = mongoose.model( 'Minder', minderSchema );

var minder = new Minder({
  "phones": [{ "number": "12345", "bill": "45678" }]
});

console.log( JSON.stringify( minder, undefined, 2 ) );


minder.save();
```

This not only separates the schema definitions ( which is handy and clean ) but now you have a clearly defined "sub-type" as it were, where the validation can be performed on the entries. You can expand on this if needed, but I generally find this the cleaner form.

A final and important point here is realizing where the "validation" actually happens. So from you example you are just creating instances, but this is not where validation happens. The only place this actually occurs is when the object instance is "saved" and persisted to storage. This allows you to "build" the objects, but is not a strict "validator" of the objects in a traditional "class" sense.

So running the snippet above, you get this output:

```
{ _id: 537d7c71d4d04b65174d0c00,
  phones: [ { number: '12345', _id: 537d7c71d4d04b65174d0c01 } ] }

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
No listeners detected, throwing. Consider adding an error listener to your connection.
ValidationError: Path `region_code` is required., Path `country_code` is required.
    at model.Document.invalidate (/home/neillunn/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1009:32)
    at EmbeddedDocument.invalidate (/home/neillunn/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/embedded.js:178:19)
    at /home/neillunn/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:958:16
    at validate (/home/neillunn/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:610:7)
    at /home/neillunn/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:627:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate     (/home/neillunn/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:614:19)
    at /home/neillunn/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:956:9
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
```

Noting that the "log" output there kept the "valid" entry but discarded the field that was not defined, and then the "validation" really only occurs for the required fields *only when* the object actually attempts to "save".

So consider your structure and also what is actually happening with validation in place. Trying to add a field that is not defined does not error, it just discards. Omitting a "required" field, is only checked when the object is persisted which allows you time to build it. These are not required "class constructor" type arguments, but for a different purpose.

---

If you really want nesting, drop the "type" declaration as in:

```
var phonesSchema = new Schema({
  details: {
    country_code: { type: String, required: true },
    region_code: { type: String, required: true },
    number: { type: String, required: true }
  }
});
```

And the validation will work for you:

```
{
  "_id": "537d9e6d5b433f8745547f52",
  "phones": [
    {
      "_id": "537d9e6d5b433f8745547f53",
      "details": {
        "number": "12345"
      }
    }
  ]
}

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
No listeners detected, throwing. Consider adding an error listener to your connection.
ValidationError: Path `details.region_code` is required., Path `details.country_code` is required.
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for taking the time. I knew I could do the example you did above, however it is different to what I want. It is just a sub document schema inside an array i.e. phones:[phonesSchema]. What I would like is to actually have the phonesSchema also contain sub documents NOT inside arrays. For now I have settled on having the country code etc on the same level as the number

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra Probably should have originally expanded on that in the answer. See the additional details at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for the nested documents I used this module [mongoose-unique-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator), but you can also use `SchemaName.path("key.nestedKey").validate(argument => {}))`, so the problem was that on `update` Mongoose just do the parse of the query and run without validate, to validate you can pass as the third argument `{ runValidators: true }`

Comment: Validators operate with caveats on updates. Switching it on blindly isn't a great idea. Also, the question was nothing to do with `unique` values.